# Sustain dropdown on row while table refreshes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a table which refreshes every few seconds. On each row, I have a dropdown (from ui.bootstrap) which allows the user to perform actions on that row.

The issue is that upon getting new data from the DB, if the dropdown is open, it closes. This is quite annoying for the users.

I did originally just have separate buttons on the row to perform the actions, but I can see that the list of actions is likely to grow, so would like to move to a dropdown.

```
    <tbody ng-repeat="item in items">
        <tr>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.age}}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group" dropdown>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Action</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" dropdown-toggle>
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Split button!</span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a>Edit</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Delete</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

I've done a plunkr to demonstrate [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ohhEKBkPNCJT3fD7Nmle?p=preview), probably easier than be waffling on! If you click a dropdown and wait a few seconds, you'll see it disappear.

Any advise is very much appreciated.

**Edit**:
Thanks to **Denocle** for his answer, here... [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6vwBnmbsJQvDxHoxLJ70?p=preview)

...and also I've refined his method slightly without using IDs in the DOM, here... [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zyQUUqQwiCWxovr41QTD?p=preview)

Thanks for the help and comments.

Comment: Could you make it so the table doesn't refresh when the dropdown is open? Or does the data need to be updated all the time?

Comment: Hi, the data changes quite often as it tracks a large number of items through a workflow, so would ideally like it to remain updated in all cases. It is an option that I could investigate though. Others options I have are only updating the row if the data for that row has changed, or having an actions menu outside of the <tr> and it acting upon the row that is currently highlighted. Just wondering if there is a way to do it this way first.

Comment: Does the number of rows change as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have a unique ID to all your rows, you can save the ID of the row that you have the dropdown open for, before you refresh, and then find that row after the data has updated to the add the "open" class to the btn-group on that row.

I forked your demonstration with a working example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/6vwBnmbsJQvDxHoxLJ70

```js
// Method for saving and restoring the correct dropdown

api.saveOpenBtnGroup = function() {
  this.openBtnGroupItemId = null;
  var openBtnGroup = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-group open');
  if (openBtnGroup.length > 0) {
    this.openBtnGroupItemId = openBtnGroup[0].getAttribute('data-item-id');
  }
}

api.restoreOpenBtnGroup = function() {
  if (this.openBtnGroupItemId !== null) {
    var btnGroup = document.querySelectorAll('[data-item-id="' + this.openBtnGroupItemId + '"]');
    if (btnGroup.length == 1) {
      console.log(btnGroup[0].className);
      btnGroup[0].className = btnGroup[0].className + ' open';
      console.log(btnGroup[0].className);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Adding the unique item id to the btn-group so we can find it later -->
<div class="btn-group" dropdown data-item-id="{{item.id}}">
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. While you were working on that, I did something similar, both seem to work. I'll mark yours as the answer though, and put both as links in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative, if you just change the contents of the array, opposed to changing the array itself, the dropdown will remain open:

```
function getItems() {
    $scope.i++;
    console.log("refresh");
    //$scope.items = api.getStuff();
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item){
      item.age = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    })
}
```