# $location.search() makes angular-ui-bootstrap's tooltip disappearing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

When I implemented in my code mechanism to change url's query in background (using `$location.search`), it caused disappearing all tooltips which have option `tooltip-append-to-body`, at the moment of changing url value. I need `tooltip-append-to-body` attribute because of another reasons (the simplest solution is to remove it but that's not the solution for me).

My code looks like this:

js:

```
angular.module('mapp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap'])
config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');

  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      reloadOnSearch: false,
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    });
  }
])

.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$location',function($scope, $timeout, $location) {
  var value = 0;
  var runTimeout = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      $location.search('start', value++);
      runTimeout();
    }, 500);
  };
  runTimeout();
}]);
```

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="mapp" ng-controller="myCtrl" style="">
  <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
```

home.html:

```
<a href="#" data-tooltip="Refreshed tooltip" tooltip-append-to-body="true">tooltip</a>
```

Here you have plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/DkmcSMGmYAowbI4rNQ6W?p=preview.

Comment: You could try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134574/sustain-dropdown-on-row-while-table-refreshes.  I realize the tooltip doesn't typically get fired programmatically, but underneath it uses the same code as the popover, so you can fire whatever trigger is set for the tooltip element to open it and even create custom triggers.

Comment: I don't see how could I do it. Popover has its dropdown set as hidden, tooltip creates its element ad hoc. Is there another way to connect this code with popover?

Comment: What I mean is something like:  Broadcast an event that you can listen for before you refresh your page and after you refresh.  Add your own directive to the popover that when it receives the refresh event checks to see if the tooltip is open and sets a flag.  Then when it receives the after event, it would check if its flag is set and if yes, run element.trigger('mouseenter').

Comment: Ok, I see, but I'm not sure if tooltip won't be flashing (due to animation).

Comment: Probably...but you could pass the $animate service to your custom directive and do: $animate.enabled(false, element);